# How to create events and reminders in Google Glass?

Tags: android, google-glass

I am exploring the Google Glass APIs. How do I create events or reminders in the Google Glass calendar for an end user? [The XE11 release notes](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3534429?hl=en) say there are options for end users to access their calendar but I could not find how to programmatically add events to it.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar integration is actually with the Google Calendar. You can use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) to add events, then Google Glass will take care of showing the events at the appropriate timing, according to the current Google Calendar integration within Glass.

Comment: thanks for the reply. "according to the current Google Calendar integration within Glass" does it mean that Glass is not having in built calender like Android device ?

Comment: Yeah, the integration mentioned is integration with Google Calendar, not an Android calendar.